# Xtext integration in Maven program returning error - using injector and MyDslStandaloneSetup

Tags: maven, xtext, eclipse-emf

I am integrating my Xtext DSL into Maven following the tutorial : https://github.com/echebbi/standalone-xtext-example/tree/master

However, when I run my main class in Maven, it throws error when `Injector injector = new MyDslStandaloneSetup().createInjectorAndDoEMFRegistration();`

My code is in: https://github.com/Gricel-lee/Xtext-Maven/tree/main.

I guess there is some dependent/plugin version in the pom.xlm file?

Thanks for any help.

The error log is:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:553)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:419)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$CustomConcurrentHashMap$ComputingImpl.get(CustomConcurrentHashMap.java:2041)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache.get(FailableCache.java:50)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.get(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:49)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.initialize(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:125)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeJitBinding(InjectorImpl.java:521)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:847)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:772)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:256)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:205)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInternalFactory(InjectorImpl.java:853)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.notify(FactoryProxy.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProcessedBindingData.runCreationListeners(ProcessedBindingData.java:50)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:106)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:95)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:72)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.common.TerminalsStandaloneSetupGenerated.createInjector(TerminalsStandaloneSetupGenerated.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.common.TerminalsStandaloneSetupGenerated.createInjectorAndDoEMFRegistration(TerminalsStandaloneSetupGenerated.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.common.TerminalsStandaloneSetup.doSetup(TerminalsStandaloneSetup.java:11)
    at zzz.example.mydsl1.MyDslStandaloneSetupGenerated.createInjectorAndDoEMFRegistration(MyDslStandaloneSetupGenerated.java:21)
    at run.main(run.java:19)
Caused by: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:553)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:419)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$CustomConcurrentHashMap$ComputingImpl.get(CustomConcurrentHashMap.java:2041)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache.get(FailableCache.java:50)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.get(MembersInjectorStore.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.createConstructor(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:73)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.access$000(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:28)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:36)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:32)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache$1.apply(FailableCache.java:39)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:549)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:553)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:419)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$CustomConcurrentHashMap$ComputingImpl.get(CustomConcurrentHashMap.java:2041)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache.get(FailableCache.java:50)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.get(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:49)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.initialize(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:125)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeJitBinding(InjectorImpl.java:521)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:847)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:772)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:256)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:205)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createImplementedByBinding(InjectorImpl.java:732)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createUninitializedBinding(InjectorImpl.java:618)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:845)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:772)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:256)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:205)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInternalFactory(InjectorImpl.java:853)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleFieldInjector.<init>(SingleFieldInjector.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.getInjectors(MembersInjectorStore.java:125)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.createWithListeners(MembersInjectorStore.java:95)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.access$000(MembersInjectorStore.java:34)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore$1.create(MembersInjectorStore.java:42)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore$1.create(MembersInjectorStore.java:39)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache$1.apply(FailableCache.java:39)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:549)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:553)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:419)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$CustomConcurrentHashMap$ComputingImpl.get(CustomConcurrentHashMap.java:2041)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache.get(FailableCache.java:50)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.get(MembersInjectorStore.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.createConstructor(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:73)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.access$000(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:28)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:36)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:32)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache$1.apply(FailableCache.java:39)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:549)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:553)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:419)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$CustomConcurrentHashMap$ComputingImpl.get(CustomConcurrentHashMap.java:2041)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache.get(FailableCache.java:50)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.get(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:49)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.initialize(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:125)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeJitBinding(InjectorImpl.java:521)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:847)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:772)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:256)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:205)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createImplementedByBinding(InjectorImpl.java:732)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createUninitializedBinding(InjectorImpl.java:618)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:845)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:772)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:256)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:205)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInternalFactory(InjectorImpl.java:853)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleFieldInjector.<init>(SingleFieldInjector.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.getInjectors(MembersInjectorStore.java:125)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.createWithListeners(MembersInjectorStore.java:95)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.access$000(MembersInjectorStore.java:34)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore$1.create(MembersInjectorStore.java:42)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore$1.create(MembersInjectorStore.java:39)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache$1.apply(FailableCache.java:39)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:549)
    ... 68 more
Caused by: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:553)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:419)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$CustomConcurrentHashMap$ComputingImpl.get(CustomConcurrentHashMap.java:2041)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache.get(FailableCache.java:50)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.get(MembersInjectorStore.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.createConstructor(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:73)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.access$000(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:28)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:36)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:32)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache$1.apply(FailableCache.java:39)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:549)
    ... 93 more
Caused by: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:553)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:419)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$CustomConcurrentHashMap$ComputingImpl.get(CustomConcurrentHashMap.java:2041)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache.get(FailableCache.java:50)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.get(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:49)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.initialize(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:125)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeJitBinding(InjectorImpl.java:521)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:847)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:772)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:256)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:205)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createImplementedByBinding(InjectorImpl.java:732)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createUninitializedBinding(InjectorImpl.java:618)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:845)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:772)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:256)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:205)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInternalFactory(InjectorImpl.java:853)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleFieldInjector.<init>(SingleFieldInjector.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.getInjectors(MembersInjectorStore.java:125)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.createWithListeners(MembersInjectorStore.java:95)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.access$000(MembersInjectorStore.java:34)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore$1.create(MembersInjectorStore.java:42)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore$1.create(MembersInjectorStore.java:39)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache$1.apply(FailableCache.java:39)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:549)
    ... 103 more
Caused by: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:553)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:419)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$CustomConcurrentHashMap$ComputingImpl.get(CustomConcurrentHashMap.java:2041)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache.get(FailableCache.java:50)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.get(MembersInjectorStore.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.createConstructor(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:73)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.access$000(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:28)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:36)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:32)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache$1.apply(FailableCache.java:39)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:549)
    ... 128 more
Caused by: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:553)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:419)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$CustomConcurrentHashMap$ComputingImpl.get(CustomConcurrentHashMap.java:2041)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache.get(FailableCache.java:50)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.get(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:49)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.initialize(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:125)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeJitBinding(InjectorImpl.java:521)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:847)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:772)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:256)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:205)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createImplementedByBinding(InjectorImpl.java:732)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createUninitializedBinding(InjectorImpl.java:618)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:845)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:772)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:256)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:205)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInternalFactory(InjectorImpl.java:853)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleFieldInjector.<init>(SingleFieldInjector.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.getInjectors(MembersInjectorStore.java:125)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.createWithListeners(MembersInjectorStore.java:95)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.access$000(MembersInjectorStore.java:34)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore$1.create(MembersInjectorStore.java:42)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore$1.create(MembersInjectorStore.java:39)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache$1.apply(FailableCache.java:39)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:549)
    ... 138 more
Caused by: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:553)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:419)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$CustomConcurrentHashMap$ComputingImpl.get(CustomConcurrentHashMap.java:2041)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache.get(FailableCache.java:50)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.get(MembersInjectorStore.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.createConstructor(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:73)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.access$000(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:28)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:36)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:32)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache$1.apply(FailableCache.java:39)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:549)
    ... 163 more
Caused by: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:553)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:419)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$CustomConcurrentHashMap$ComputingImpl.get(CustomConcurrentHashMap.java:2041)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache.get(FailableCache.java:50)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.get(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:49)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.initialize(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:125)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeJitBinding(InjectorImpl.java:521)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:847)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:772)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:256)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:205)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createImplementedByBinding(InjectorImpl.java:732)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createUninitializedBinding(InjectorImpl.java:618)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:845)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:772)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:256)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:205)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInternalFactory(InjectorImpl.java:853)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleFieldInjector.<init>(SingleFieldInjector.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.getInjectors(MembersInjectorStore.java:125)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.createWithListeners(MembersInjectorStore.java:95)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.access$000(MembersInjectorStore.java:34)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore$1.create(MembersInjectorStore.java:42)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore$1.create(MembersInjectorStore.java:39)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache$1.apply(FailableCache.java:39)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:549)
    ... 173 more
Caused by: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:553)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:419)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$CustomConcurrentHashMap$ComputingImpl.get(CustomConcurrentHashMap.java:2041)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache.get(FailableCache.java:50)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.get(MembersInjectorStore.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.createConstructor(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:73)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.access$000(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:28)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:36)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:32)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache$1.apply(FailableCache.java:39)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:549)
    ... 198 more
Caused by: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:553)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:419)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$CustomConcurrentHashMap$ComputingImpl.get(CustomConcurrentHashMap.java:2041)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache.get(FailableCache.java:50)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.get(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:49)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.initialize(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:125)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeJitBinding(InjectorImpl.java:521)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:847)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:772)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:256)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:205)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInternalFactory(InjectorImpl.java:853)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleFieldInjector.<init>(SingleFieldInjector.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.getInjectors(MembersInjectorStore.java:125)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.createWithListeners(MembersInjectorStore.java:95)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.access$000(MembersInjectorStore.java:34)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore$1.create(MembersInjectorStore.java:42)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore$1.create(MembersInjectorStore.java:39)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache$1.apply(FailableCache.java:39)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:549)
    ... 208 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClassEmitter.<init>(FastClassEmitter.java:67)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.generateClass(FastClass.java:72)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.create(FastClass.java:64)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClass(BytecodeGen.java:207)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.create(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProxyFactory.create(ProxyFactory.java:153)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.createConstructor(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:89)
    ... 241 more
```